# Too little current to trigger a relay?

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

I try to use [this relay](https://www.banggood.com/2Pcs-5V-1-Channel-Level-Trigger-Optocoupler-Relay-Module-For-Arduino-p-1366337.html?cur_warehouse=CN) with a Arduino Mega. I connected with jumper cables

- 5V pin to DC+,
- GND to DC- and
- Digital Pin 13 (because its a lucky number) to IN.

The power LED from the relay is lighting green.

I run this code, which should trigger the relay every 3s for 3s:

```
int pinOut = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {             
  digitalWrite(pinOut, LOW);
  delay(3000);

  digitalWrite(pinOut, HIGH);
  delay(3000);            
}
```

When initializing the sketch, the red light (from the relay) is flashing and the relay is clicking. But afterwards nothing happens.

With my multimeter I check the currents:

- 5V to GND = ~5V
- Pin13 to GND, when not connected to relay = ~4.7V
- Pin13 to GND, when connected to relay = ~1.2V

The relay needs 5V and 5mA triggering current. I don't think the Arduino is not suited, since they promote the relay Arduino.

Any ideas? Do I need some kind of resistor? Or is the USB port from the laptop not sufficient? I used two different Arduino Mega's with two different relays. By the way i don't have a big background in electric.

Comment: but what do you want with not so lucky 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using pin 13, but you set pin 10 as an OUTPUT.

`pinMode(10, OUTPUT);`

Try changing that to

`pinMode(pinOut, OUTPUT);`

PS by not setting pin 13 to OUTPUT, `digitalWrite(pinOut, HIGH);` enables the internal pull-up, instead of "connecting" it to 5V. The internal resistors are around 35kOhm. So pulling a bit of current through them will result in a lower voltage at the pin.

Comment: OMG it is working now. I was trying for hours and in the end it was just a wrong number. Thanks a lot.

Comment: We've all been there. (-;

Comment: There but for the grace of god go I. The hardest bugs to fix are ones where you see what you expect to see, not what's there. Good catch. (Voted)